# Bootstrap не работает dropdown menu

Tags: html, bootstrap, bootstrap4, dropdown, navigationbar

я сделал навигационный меню бар и добавил в нем dropdown меню но оно не работает и я не знаю почему.Если можете помогите мне понять почему же оно не работает

вот сам код

```
 <div class="container">
              <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
                     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
                     <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">

                                   <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                          Dropdown
                                   </a>
                                   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SubPage 1</a></li>
                                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SubPage 2</a></li>
                                          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SubPage 3</a></li>
                                   </ul>
                            </li>
                     </ul>

                     <form class="form-inline">

                            <input type="text" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                     </form>
              </nav>
       </div>
```

Comment: класс `dropdown-item` перенесите из `a` в `li`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо Вы забыли добавить необходимые js-библиотеки:

- jQuery
- Bootstrap.js
- Popper.js

  [Документация](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#js)

Вот ваш пример, который отлично работает:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">

        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                          Dropdown
                                   </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SubPage 1</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SubPage 2</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">SubPage 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <form class="form-inline">

      <input type="text" class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="Search">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </nav>
</div>
```